# Свой справочник в расширении

Tags: 1с, расширения

Добавил свой справочник в расширение. При  обновлении программа ругается на то, что об этом справочнике нет записей в справочнике метаданных и не найден идентификатор в регистре сведений идентификаторы объектов версий расширений.
Можно ли что-то сделать с этим или придется перенести все в основную конфигурацию?

Comment: Какая версия плафтормы, БСП?

Comment: Платформа: 8.3.14.1565

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, поможет запуск с параметром:
/С ЗапуститьОбновлениеИнформационнойБазы

Результат не гарантирую, сам не сталкивался.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ.
Не поможет. Пробовал.

Comment: Вероятно, БСП в конфигурации устаревшая и не умеет работать со справочниками из расширения. Не знаю, могу ли я оставлять тут ссылки, поэтому подскажу, что по словам "не найден идентификатор в регистре сведений идентификаторы объектов версий расширений" можно нагуглить статью с решением.
Вполне может быть, что "дешевле" будет просто встроить ваш справочник в конфигурацию.

Comment: Так в итоге и поступил)
А жаль! Я так понял, что в регистр метаданных пишутся только объекты, которые есть в основной конфигурации + роли, подсистемы, перечисления из расширения.